# How to have custom table captions A-1 instead of 1-A? ms word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to add appendix section, so the appendix need to be numbered as "**Table A-1:** List of pictures"

When I go to "Insert caption" --> "format", in MS word, it shows options to select `A,B,C` etc the issue is,

1. It adds letters in reverse order. Eg: **Table 1-A**. However, I want it to be **Table A-1, Table A-2** etc How to do that?
2. Although I added a page break, the numbering system gets applied to whole document. I want it to be only applied to the last page.

I'm on macOS

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have some Paragraph Heading levels spare, the simplest way to do this is described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-number-chapters-appendixes-and-pages-in-documents-that-contain-both-chapter-and-appendix-headings-in-word-2d9a939c-2863-45c3-bf5e-74b32972035d)

What this tells you is that you need to use the Multi-level list numbering feature to number your Headings. e.g. start by applying the Format that looks like

```
1. Heading 1
1.1 Heading 2
etc.
```

Like this...

[Multilevel Numbering selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w59nM.png)

Then click *Define New Multi-level List...*.

On the left, select Level 7. Delete everything in the *Enter Formatting for number:* box, then type `Appendix` followed by a space in the box.

In the *Number style for this level:* dropdown, select **A, B, C, ...**

You should see an `A` appear after the word `Appendix`.

Ignore the *Include level number from:* setting (it shouldn't say **Level 1** IMO, but you cannot eliminate it.

If you are going to need numbered subheadings in your Appendix, set up levels 8 and 9 as you need them. e.g. Typically in level 8 you would delete the word Appendix, and include the numbering from Level 7.

Like this:

[Customise Outline Numbered List dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOJTX.png)

Then, back in your document, apply the appropriate Heading 1 to Heading 9 styles, e.g. Heading  to your Appendix title.

Then, when you insert your captions, in the *Caption* dialog box, click *Numbering:* **Format...**.

Then in the *Caption Numbering* dialog, in the *Format:* dropdown, select **1,2,3, ...**, check *Include chapter number*, and in the *Chapter starts with style:* dropdown, select **Heading 7**

Like this:

[Caption Numbering dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz5V5.png)

The caption should look something like *Table A-1*

If you select the caption, right-click and click *Toggle Field Codes* you should see the field coding for this caption, which should be something like this:

```
Table { STYLEREF 7 \s }-{ SEQ Table \* ARABIC \s 7 }
```

(You can select, right-click and Toggle the field codes again to hide them.

The STYLEREF field picks up its text from the most recent paragraph with style *Heading 7* . The SEQ field says "use ARABIC, i.e. 1,2,3, numbering, and restart numbering at each level 7 paragraph". It's probably simpler to delete and re-insert any captions you have already inserted, but you could also consider @fixing up@ the existing ones, which will probably have the wrong level numbers, and probably show `\* ALPHABETIC` instead of `\* ARABIC`

[Just guessing, but what you are probably doing at the moment is something like this...

In the *Caption* dialog box, you click *Numbering:* **Format...**

The *Caption Numbering* dialog displays and you select *Format:* **A,B,C, ...** and *Chapter starts with style:* **Heading 1** (or some such). Like this:

[Caption Numbering dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEmHJ.png)

Then when you click *OK* to go back to the *Caption* dialog box, where you see something like this:

[Caption dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YsXY.png)

]